# What does it mean to find a basis that "diagonalizes" a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I'm having a hugely hard time wrapping my head around this statement. I am trying to figure it out on my own but I just don't get it. The terminology is weird to me and I can't really picture what it "looks like" in my head.

Could someone refer me to some literature that may clear this up?

Could someone give a "diagonalization-for-dummies" answer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix

Comment: This was good, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you find a set of independent vectors $(e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_n)$ such that 
$$ f(e_1) = \lambda_1 e_1,$$
$$ f(e_2) = \lambda_2 e_2,$$
$$ \cdots $$
$$ f(e_n) = \lambda_n e_n$$
Thus in this basis the matrix of the transformation is like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Wow, so perfect. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidSouth Geometrically, if you transform a sphere in $n$ dimensions, the basis represents the principal axes of the resulting ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis for a vector space, and $L$ is a linear map on the space, then $L(v_k)$ will be some complicated sum of all the basis elements. It is best when $L(v_k)$ is a multiple of itself, that is as good as it can be. We call that "diagonolizable" basis.